# Merge commit reverts multiple commits in target branch

Tags: git

I have been working on a branch with several commits, say A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J.
A co-worker of mine was working on another branch which was spawned from my B commit.
This week, he merged his commits into my branch.
I then did a `git pull` so that I apply his changes to the one I was working on.
This action added commits K, L.
Commit K looked like a regular commit, and commit L looked like a merge commit.

But surprisingly, when I did this pull, I noticed that my code files in my commits C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J were all reverted.

I suspected that the merge commit (L) was the culprit. But because I don't know how to revert merge commits, I decided to get back my code by spawning a new branch from commit K (since it looked like a regular commit, not a merge).

But this new branch was even stranger, it contained only commits A, B, K.
I quickly deleted this new branch, and then tried to spawn a new branch from commit J, which was my last commit before my co-worker was involved.
When I did that, the new branch contained A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J.
So I got back my code at least.

My question is: Why did my commits C to J not appear in the first new branch spawned from my co-worker's commit K? Commit K looked like a regular commit (not a merge commit).

Comment: *"I then did a GIT PULL so that I apply his changes to the one I was working on."* - risky move, unless its a stable branch (not in progress features) and you need stuff from there it kinda make stuff complicated if the pulled branch removes files later on.

Comment: *"commit L looked like a merge commit"* - perhaps you should grab a gui for git, something like gitkraken or source tree so you can visualise the changes better. also, im curious whether you are doing a fast forward merge or not. if it is, you might want to resort to `git reset`.

Comment: Does commit `L` have your name on it or your coworker's?

Comment: Commit L has my coworker's name on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your starting situation. Your branch had commits C-J on top of B while your coworker's branch had K on top of B:

```
        +-- C <-- D <-- E <-- F <-- G <-- H <-- I <-- J (your-branch)
       /
      v 
A <-- B
      ^
       \
        +-- K (his-branch)
```

Then your coworker created a merge commit between J and K:

```
        +-- C <-- D <-- E <-- F <-- G <-- H <-- I <-- J
       /                                              ^
      v                                                \
A <-- B                                                 +-- L (your-branch)
      ^                                                /
       \                                              /
        +-- K <--------------------------------------+
```

It sounds like merge commit L was made incorrectly. While it had metadata saying that its parents were J and K, it failed to actually incorporate the changes from C-J into the merge. That's entirely possible to do by accident, particularly if there were merge conflicts and your coworker overwrote your changes instead of hand-merging them.

Reverting to K didn't show your changes because K branched off of B, not J.

Comment: Agreed, running `git show <tree-ish>` onto merge commit is a good way to see whether there were any conflicts, if some changes are shown - it's about conflict, otherwise - it was regular conflictless merge commit.

Comment: @Ryan Unfortunately, not. When `git show merge_commit` does not show anything, it can also mean that all conflicts were resolved by taking one side's content. This is barely ever the right way to resolve a conflict. A no-output `git show` should be regarded suspicious *if* conflicts are to be expected. Unfortunately again, this situation cannot be distinguished from a merge that was genuinely without conflicts by looking only at the merge commit.

Comment: I think I'm understanding that the merge commit L made by my coworker was most likely made incorrectly. But how do I prove it to him? I need to somehow show him that merge commit L was missing my commits in the commit metadata.

Comment: I don't think it's missing your commits in a metadata sense. It has the correct parentage, since you got commit L when you ran `git pull`. It just doesn't have the right file contents. Fundamentally, a commit is not a diff against other commits; it's a snapshot of all the files in the repo. If the snapshot in L doesn't have the changes introduced in C-J, then it doesn't matter if the metadata says J is a parent. The snapshot is what really matters.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your co-worker messed up the merge. One easy way to confirm this is to just retry the merge yourself:

```
git switch -c test-branch J # create a temporary branch at J to test the merge
git merge K # merge in your co-worker's change
# resolve any conflicts if required, then complete the merge
```

Now you should have a new (improved) merge commit that shows what you expect. You can compare it with the previous version:

```
git diff test-branch my-branch # Or replace "my-branch" with commit L
```

If that diff shows an undo of your changes like before, then you've confirmed your suspicion. You could now consider making this your branch and force pushing it to replace the remote version with the fixed version. I would discuss with your co-worker to make sure you are both on the same page about this, and so they know to delete their local copy of your branch so they can get the new version.

As for this question:

> Why did my commits C to J not appear in the first new branch spawned from my co-worker's commit K? Commit K looked like a regular commit (not a merge commit).

It's because commit `K` started from your branch back when it was pointing to commit `B`. Branches are simply named pointers to a specific commit, and the fact that you added more commits to your branch after `B`, isn't relevant to the newly created branch. When you create a new branch from another branch, it is the same as if you created it from a specific commit ID rather than the branch name. For example, suppose branch `main` points to commit ID `abcd1234` right now. The following commands would have the same result:

```
git switch -c new-branch main

# OR

git switch -c new-branch abcd1234
```

In both cases, `new-branch` will be pointing to commit ID `abcd1234`. And at the moment, `main` also happens to be pointing to the same commit ID.